# criar intro page em site multilingual

Tags: framework, joomla, html

Não consigo criar uma `intro` `page` no meu site e acredito que o problema seja relacionado ao multilanguage ativado. Alguém  sabe como resolver isto? estou usando o `Framework` Vertex.

Comment: Sua pergunta é vaga, confusa, não esclarece. Qual a sua dúvida exatamente? Você já tem alguma coisa pronta?

Answer (score -1):

Penso que este **vídeo** poderá ser uma possível **ajuda** para o seu problema:

http://www.shape5.com/documentation/Joomla/Getting-Started/How-To-Setup-Multilanguage-Support-In-Joomla

Comment: Sua resposta não atende os requisitos. Imagine se esse link ficar off line, sua resposta não tem sentido. Tente criar uma resposta com conteúdo.